# Blocked by the CORS policy in the get method

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, react-tsx

I made my backend using springboot and added CORS to all the routes:

```
package com.sysmap.showus.services.utils.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Now I'm doing the frontend with React Typescript and to create and log into the account it works by passing the correct CORS header, but to do a get that returns me a user it's not returning the header and always gives an error:

> 'p://localhost:8082/api/v1/user?email=l%40gmail.com' from origin
> 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Does anyone know what this could be?
Here is the Frontend API call that gives the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const res = async () => {
      const userEmail = localStorage.getItem('userEmail');
      if (userEmail) {
        await api
          .get('/user', {
            headers: getAuthHeader(),
            params: {
              email: userEmail,
            },
          })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
          });
      }
    };
    res();
  }, []);
```

I tried putting the `@CrossOrigin` tag in all routes in the springboot but it gives the same result.

Comment: did you try to allowCredentials ?

Comment: yes, I did that and the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

My way of dealing with CORS is setting proxy, create new file, name it however you want, and use the code below. Have in mind that you should switch target url to your servers url, and of course run npm i http-proxy-middleware in client. One reminder '/api' means that every endpoint you will create on your BE will need to start with /api for example /api/get-users

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8080', changeOrigin: true }));
};
```

Comment: This is nonsensical. If you control the client and the server, injecting a proxy just to bypass CORS is the worst possible way of doing this.

Comment: Its not just to bypass CORS, its all in one

Comment: "All in one"? What does that even mean?

Comment: Well, it's not only for CORS, but I am dealing with CORS like that too, I said my way of dealing with CORS, because my FE and BE is supposed to be running on same URL, of course you can do it with restify's CORS or whatever node server you are using.

Comment: OK, so you **are** suggesting introducing a proxy to get around CORS between your own front-end and back-end, which is objectively wrong, and avoids solving the real problem by layering on a whole new service. I reiterate, this is the worst possible way of doing this. If your backend is introducing overly restrictive CORS headers, using a proxy to remove them is terrible incorrect advice.